# Organise long strings in Rails Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm writing test, for my server which handles SNS notification from AWS S3 (SNS is sent whenever there's a file uploaded to S3)

Since the test string is very long, in the code it is like the pic below:

[image: current code, structure only]

The message is copied directly from what I got in the real notification. Since the message string is very long, I think I should be able to put it into a separate file to properly group it.

Is there any existing method / gem doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you could just put that stuff in spec/fixtures/approved_responses and do something like:

```
expect(response.body).to eql File.open(
  fixture_path.join('approved_responses/response_XYZ').read
)
```

Comment: i would just add the `.json` extension to the fixture files

Comment: Thanks for your idea.. would implement that way. BTW I think u missed a `)`